# HDD Partition Not able to find and copy my data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I would like to inform you that yesterday i.e.on 17-08-2016 i received my laptop from an online store. The specs are as follows:

*

> **Dell Vostro series with processor i3 (5th gen.) 4GB RAM 1 TB HDD and
>   Ubuntu 14.4 OS**.

*

I am new to Ubuntu OS and I tried to search various websites to know how to know HDD partition on my laptop to save my data into it. Even trying for like more than 2-3 hrs I couldn't find the partition that we can easily see on a Microsoft Windows OS and coz of which i am not at all able to transfer my data onto my laptop's HDD.

Please help in this regard as I really like the way Ubuntu is designed however I am unable to perform the most important and basic thing that I need.

**Please help me asap...**

*Arun Yadav*

Answer (score 0):

If login as a user you can open a terminal and do a "df -h" and "df -h ."
The different is that the first "df" Command will show you all File systems - including the system. the second "df" means it will show "disk full"-information of you home.
With this overview you should be able to understand what is user's home directory and what is your systems file system. Normal your user home is located in /home/ or you can do also "echo $HOME" in a terminal.
There are main differentces between Windows and Linux/Unix. Linux is not dealing with "drive" in terms of drive-letters. Everything is a file !

Answer (score 0):

> df -h

will list the drives mounted in he machine or available drives that can be used.

if any un partitioned disk space available then that can be checked from **fdisk** command and using the same command partitions can be created. Check for detailed info about fdisk

also **parted -l** will list raw disk available in the machine.